# What is the Elliptic Curve algorithm used in Ripple to generate public / private key pairs?

Tags: ripple, cryptography

The algorithm used by bitcoin to generate keys is secp256k1, is it the same for ripple?

Answer (score 2):

Yes in ripple-lib the default elliptic curve is set in [sjcl-custom/sjcl-secp256k1.js](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib/blob/develop/src/js/sjcl-custom/sjcl-secp256k1.js)

```
// Overwrite NIST-P256 with secp256k1 so we're on even footing
sjcl.ecc.curves.c256 = new sjcl.ecc.curve(...)
```

Then in [keypair.js](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib/blob/develop/src/js/ripple/keypair.js) when a new key pair is instantiated its `_curve` attribute is set to secp256k1.

```
function KeyPair() {
  this._curve  = sjcl.ecc.curves['c256'];
  this._secret = null;
  this._pubkey = null;
};
```